# Try to separate words from pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I try to separate words form DataFrame Columns:

```
Binary = []
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    if data['attack'][i] == 'normal':
        Binary.append(1)
    else:
        Binary.append(0)
print(len(Binary))

data= pd.DataFrame({'attack':['normal','neptune','ps','normal','neptune']})
print(data)
    attack
0   normal
1  neptune
2       ps
3   normal
4  neptune
```

we want to change these column value into:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
   attack
0       1
1       0
2       0
3       1
4       0
```

only normal = `1` else `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert boolean mask to integers for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
data['attack'] = data['attack'].eq('normal').astype(int)
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with specify both values:

```
data['attack'] = np.where(data['attack'].eq('normal'), 1, 0)
```

---

```
print(data)
  attack
0       1
1       0
2       0
3       1
4       0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for index, row in data.iteritems():
for each in row.iteritems():
    if each[1] is "normal":
        print(each[0], "0")
    else:
        print(each[0], "1")
```